# jquery_ui menu ui parameter for dynamic sub-menu

Tags: jquery-ui, menu

I am trying to create a dynamic sub-menu.  For example, the top-level items are load and edit.  Whenever the menu is focused, a get JSON is called and the result used to populate the possible items to load under the load menu item.  However, the ui parameter for the select event handler no longer seems to correspond to the item clicked and calling ui.item.text() will instead return the entire text to the sub-menu.

HTML:

```
...
<ul id="menu">
        <li><div>load</div><ul id="load"></ul></li>
        <li><div>edit</div></li>
</ul>
...
```

javascript:

```
var load_populate = function ( json ) {
        var ul = $( "#load" );
        ul.empty();
        for ( let item of json ) {
                ul.append ( $( "<li>" ).append ( $( "<div>" ).text ( item.name ) ) );
        }
};
var menu_focus = function ( event, ui ) {
        $.getJSON ( load_options_url )
                .done ( load_populate );
};
var menu_select = function ( event, ui ) {
        console.log ( ui.item.text() );
};
$( "#menu" ).menu ({
        "focus" : menu_focus,
        "select" : menu_select
});
```

Clicking an item in the load sub-menu logs
`loaditem1item2item3`, etc.

Refreshing the menu did not work.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where new items are added or how `click` event is tied in. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on your code.

**Example Fiddle**

This uses POST just to simulate the AJAX activity

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qpky9ht1/53/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <div>load</div>
    <ul id="load">
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>edit</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

Adjusted to be more similar to your code.

```
$(function() {
  function makeListItem(o, n) {
    $(o).append("<li><div>" + n + "</div></li>");
  }

  $("#menu").menu({
    focus: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("FOCUS", e, ui.item);
      if (ui.item.parent().is("#menu")) {
        $.getJSON (load_options_url,
          function(json) {
            console.log("LOAD");
            $("#load").empty();
            $.each(json, function(i, m) {
              console.log("ITEM", i, m);
              makeListItem("#load", m.name);
            });
            $("#menu").menu("refresh");
          });
      }
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("SELECT", ui.item);
    }
  });
});
```

This will gather the list data in `focus` and append them. Once this is done, `refresh` method is executed on the Menu. This will assimilate all the new list items into the menu. Since `focus` can be executed on all menu items, you want to ensure you are not rebuilding the menu while focusing on sub-menu items. Hence the `if` statement.

Comment: My exact problem was trying to call refresh outside the success callback.  Since your solution has the refresh where it needs to be, accepting as answer.